# What's the purpose of a footer on each block when implementing malloc() in C?

Tags: c

I can kind of understand the purpose of having just a header on each block but I can't understand the purpose of having both a header and a footer.  According to http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2016fa/slides/15-allocation.pdf, slide 25, the footer enables traversing the list, also, backwards.  What's the purpose of traversing the list both forward and backward?

Comment: Please include any code for context in the body of the question, not as external links.

Comment: @tadman: I doubt the OP owns the copyright for the mentioned slide.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It's fair use. Not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented quite a few implementations of `malloc()`. The reason you want to traverse backwards is to attach the block onto the previous block on `free()`. But I can't imagine using a footer. I just use a header that looks like this.

```
struct block {
    struct block *next;
    struct block *prev;
    uintptr_t size;
    uintptr_t blocksize;
};
```

I could use `size_t` for size but on platforms where they differ, `uintptr_t` is more likely to work correctly, so I'm less apt to have to fix something. I keep track of the size that was allocated as well as the size of the block to speed up `realloc()`.

If we mutated away the need to traverse backwards on `free()` somehow, we could reduce the header to two elements.

```
struct block {
    struct block *next;
    uintptr_t size;
};
```

The low bit of `size` is free on any reasonable platform, so you can stick an is_allocated flag there.

Comment: This is pretty wasteful, using 4 words for the header.  With header/footer you need only one word for each.  Even better is a bibop scheme where you don't use headers or footers, just a descriptor per page.

Comment: There's no need for extra words for discontnuous heap, as long as each discontinuous chunk is aligned (as it will usually be page aligned, that is not an issue).  But generally, if you require n-byte alignment, the minimum size of header+footer is n bytes, which generally favors page-based mechanisms over list based.

Comment: Each word has the size of the chunk plus 2 bits to denote inuse/free/not part of heap status.  First block of heap starts with a 1-word footer denoting start of heap (no previous chunk or block), then 1-word header for the first chunk (free or in use) in this block.  Last word of the heap block will be a header giving the size of the gap to the next heap block indicating not part of heap.  As long as all heap blocks are 2-word aligned, all allocations will also be 2-word aligned.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I stand corrected. If your alignment constraint is pointer and your system is not 16 bit that is a solution.

Comment: So the heap becomes "continuous" from the lowest address block to the highest, it just might contain chunks in that are not part of the heap.  If you like, you could consider this a two word header rather than a 1 word header + 1 word footer, where the header contains the size of the current block and the size of the previous block as well as the allocation status of both.

Comment: A much bigger issue with mixed free/inuse linked lists like this is that you generally need a global lock for every malloc/free, which is very bad for mulitthreaded programs.  You can do some stuff with per-thread free lists, but if you're going to do that, you might as well go all the way to a page-based system with fixed size blocks on each page and no need for headers/footers at all.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: If I can use the system multi-threading, I can use the system malloc. Though maybe one day I'll write a buddy malloc because it's faster, but probably not. I only have to write malloc for deeply embedded stuff.